# torch7 : print matrix in text file with lines longer than 80 characters

Tags: neural-network, torch

I'm trying to recuperate the parameters of this NN:

```
    nn.Sequential {
      [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> output]
      (1): nn.Linear(4 -> 200)
      (2): nn.Tanh
      (3): nn.Linear(200 -> 200)
      (4): nn.Tanh
      (5): nn.Linear(200 -> 3)
      (6): nn.LogSoftMax         
    }
```

using this code :

```
print(mlp:get(1).weight)
print(mlp:get(1).bias)

print(mlp:get(3).weight)
print(mlp:get(3).bias)

print(mlp:get(5).weight)
print(mlp:get(5).bias)
```

When saving the output .lua file into text file using this command line:

```
>>th  'MyScript.lua' > NNParameters.txt
```

I get all weight matrix wrapped into segments of six columns each (Columns 1 to 6 ... Columns 193 to 198 ... Columns 199 to 200).

Is there anyway to prevent text from being wrapped and displaying weight matrix in only one block?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printT = function(t)
   t = t:view(-1)
   for i=1,t:nElement() do
      io.write(t[i] .. ',')
   end
end

printT(mlp:get(1).weight)
printT(mlp:get(1).bias)

printT(mlp:get(3).weight)
printT(mlp:get(3).bias)

printT(mlp:get(5).weight)
printT(mlp:get(5).bias)
```

Comment: This responds to my question. I just made a small change to the function printT :

`printT = function(t, nbrCols)
   t = t:view(-1)
   for i=1,t:nElement() do      
      io.write(t[i] .. ',')
      if(i % nbrCols == 0) and (i ~= 0) then
       io.write('\n')
      end
   end
end`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want to do is to save the parameters so that you can load them back in later? In that case, look at this:

https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/serialization.md

Comment: Thank you @cfh for your reply. Actually my final goal is to use these parameters in a java platform and no matter the file format (text, csv or other). the key is to have a matrix in a single block.